# Using .Net standard project in asp.net core cause exception in json serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, .net-standard

I have a project of .Net Standart class library which distributed as a nuget package.
When I  use this package for Asp.Net Core project, I get an internal exception (related to Newtonsoft Json) while using the same package and same code in a .Net Winform application works just fine.
The .Net standart code of method that throws the exception is:

```
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
dynamic jResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
foreach (dynamic feature in jResult.features)
{
...
}
```

The exception is:
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'features'

Of course The json file I read has its 'features' property and is the same Json file for both projects. This code is tested with Unit test with the same Json file.

Comment: You have a bug, perhaps a casing error.  The string has no `features` property. JSON is case-sensitive so `features` won't match `Features`. This has nothing at all to do with .NET Standard. All NuGet packages in .NET Core are .NET Standard. Post the JSON string.

Comment: `same package and same code in a .Net Winform application works just fine` but is the *string* the same? Neither JSON.NET nor .NET Core are new. Both are used by hundreds of thousands of developers in the last 5 years. JSON.NET is the default serializer in ASP.NET Core since the very first release. If there was such a problem, people would have noticed and fixed it years ago

Comment: The Json file is the same Json file for both projects.
And this code is tested with Unit test with the same Json file.

Comment: Again, you can't be the first person to notice a problem in 5 years and millions of JSON calls.  It's very easy to prove that the problem can't be reproduced. Post code that actually reproduces the problem, including the JSON string itself

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"features\":[1,2,3]}")` works just fine. Post your actual JSON string, code, *actual* exception and the package version. Changing `features` to `Features` in the current version of JSON.NET throws a NullReferenceException

Comment: Also `Features` (with a capital F) might work if the serializer has been set up properly. But ultimately, every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies. Don't do it, use a concrete class.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah I just checked and it needs to be v3.x which is 10+ years old, eek.

Comment: I suspect that if you post an example of the JSON someone will point out your problem in < 1 hour :-)

Comment: Please post an actual example JSON that you can reproduce the problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I haven't found the cause for this weird behavior of the fact that the same method in .Net Standard that pass unit tests and works good in .Net Framework, threw exception on .Net Core 
So I changed the code to use concrete classes instead of dynamic and now it runs good in all frameworks ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic jResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

You expect that jResult is some anonymously generated .net class with properties from your json, but it is really just `JObject` that casted to `dynamic`. You can access JObject fields like:

```
var jResult = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
var features = (JArray)jResult["features"];
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. `JObject` implements the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface meaning it actually handles `jResult.features` as `jResult["features"]`